# controlar el comportamiento innecesario REACT useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

tengo 3 `select` en un componente de **REACT**, la cuales contienen las regiones, ciudad, y comuna de Chile.

**LO QUE TENGO HASTA EL MOMENTO**

Cuando carga la pagina hacer una consulta a la base de datos y me rellena el `select` de **regiones**, luego obtiene el id del item seleccionado y con el `id` consulta todas la **ciudades** de esa **region** y posteriormente se hace una consulta de las **comunas** de esa **ciudad**

(region has ciudads, ciudad has comunas)[Aca esta el enlace](https://gist.github.com/juque/465814/b632f9bfbc666f92baa6e18a8b1d2e613342bbef) del repositorio de las regiones, ciudades(o provincias), y comunas de Chile, es un listado muy grande por eso no lo agrego.
Todo funciona correctamente pero..

**EL PROBLEMA**

Todo funciona a la perfeccion a simple vista, pero al analizar por consola hay dos problemas, el **primer problema es que se ejecuta varias veces**(no es un ciclo infinito, pero son muchas veces las que se ejecuta innecesariamente y creo que esto deriva al **segundo problema que es el siguiente error:**

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `3`.
Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. 
Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported 
and could change in a future version.
```

Entiendo a que se refiere, pero en este ejemplo la `Key` que debe ser unica es el `id` de la region,ciudad o comuna que **SI** es unica.

**PREGUNTAS**

Son mis primeros pasos en react, todo lo que he hecho ha sido leyendo la documentacion, habra otra forma mejor de hacerlo?, estare usando incorrectamente los `hooks`?

**CODIGO**

```javascript
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react'
import {getUrlApi, peticionAxios} from "../Funciones"

export default function RegionesComponent(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")
    let data = [], response = []
    const [regiones, setRegiones] = useState([])
    const [ciudades, setCiudades] = useState([])
    const [comunas, setComunas] = useState([])
    let url  = getUrlApi()
    
    async function cargarRegiones(){
        let urlregiones  = url+ "regiones"
        response = await peticionAxios(urlregiones,'GET',token, "")
        if(response.status===200){
            console.log("response region",response.data)
            setRegiones(response.data)
        }
        let idRegion = document.getElementById("sltRegion").value
        await handleChangeRegion(idRegion)
        console.info("idRegion",idRegion)
        let idCiudad = document.getElementById("sltCiudad").value
        console.info("idCiudad",idCiudad)
        handleChangeCiudad(idCiudad)
    }
    async function handleChangeRegion(idRegion){
        let urlciudades  = url+ `ciudades/${idRegion}`
        response = await peticionAxios(urlciudades,'GET',token, "")
        if(response.status===200){
            console.log("response ciudad",response.data)
            setCiudades(response.data)
        }
    }
    async function handleChangeCiudad(idCiudad){
        let urlciudades  = url+ `comunas/${idCiudad}`
        response = await peticionAxios(urlciudades,'GET',token, "")
        if(response.status===200){
            console.log("response comuna",response.data)
            setComunas(response.data)
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        cargarRegiones()
    }, [])
    return (
    <div className="row">
        <div className='col-md-12 col-sm-12'>
            <label >Region
                    <select className='form-control' id="sltRegion" onChange={(e)=>handleChangeRegion(e.target.value)}>
                    {
                    regiones!==undefined?
                            regiones.map(a=>{
                                return (<option value={a.id} key={a.id}>{a.nombreRegion}</option>)
                            })
                        :""
                    }
                    </select>
            </label>   
        </div>
        <div className='col-md-6 col-sm-12'>
            <label >Provincia
                    <select className='form-control' id="sltCiudad"  onChange={(e)=>handleChangeCiudad(e.target.value)}>
                    {
                    ciudades!==undefined?
                            ciudades.map(a=>{
                                return (<option value={a.id} key={a.id}>{a.nombreCiudad}</option>)
                            })
                        :""
                    }
                    </select>
            </label>   
        </div>
        <div className='col-md-6 col-sm-12'>
            <label >Comuna
                    <select className='form-control' id="sltComuna">
                    {
                    comunas!==undefined?
                            comunas.map(a=>{
                                console.log("coumnas id",a.id)
                                return (<option value={a.id} key={a.id}>{a.nombreComuna}</option>)
                            })
                        :""
                    }
                    </select>
            </label>   
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}
```

**CONSOLA/LOG**
[image: Consola]

Comment: Podrías agregar los logs de la consola por los que dices que `son muchas veces las que se ejecuta innecesariamente`

Comment: @AndresGardiol gracias por tu comentario, editare la pregunta para complementarla

Comment: Por qué chequeas `regiones!==undefined` si el estado inicial es un array vacío? (`const [regiones, setRegiones] = useState([])`)

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en que en tu función `cargarRegiones()` estás llamando a `handleChangeRegion()` y a `handleChangeCiudad()`, revisa bien los valores por defecto de cada select

Comment: Entiendo, realmente lo hago es porque con la respuesta de la API el select de regiones se pobla y el `select` no tiene como primera opcion un "seleccione", si no que su primera opcion es la primera region del listado, por eso obtiene el primer `id`, y ejecuta handleChangeRegiones() para buscar las **ciudades/provincias** de esa region, y de la misma forma para buscar la comuna.

Comment: En cuanto a la otra duda `regiones!==undefined` tienes razon deberia reemplazarlo por un `regiones.length>0`